# How do I create a custom plugin in Google Cloud similar to a Salesforce Plugin?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I would like to create a custom plugin for Google Cloud, similar to how Salesforce allow user to easily and quickly create custom plugin to do whatever they need, either it be a custom page, or a custom object, or a custom class.  Does Google allow similar customization?

For this question, if anyone could point in the right direction with either a get started guide, or a tutorial, similar to the thousands of similar help pages on Salesforce would be great.

Comment: One of the [Google cloud how-to guides](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/plugins).

Comment: That's only for Apache Airflow